# Encoding issue with ageRange URL in linked in

Tags: linkedin-api, urn

I am fetching the audiene count

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/audienceCountsV2?q=targetingCriteriaV2&targetingCriteria=(include:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Alocations:List(urn%3Ali%3Acountry%3Aal))))),exclude:(and:List((or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AageRange:List(urn%3Ali%3AageRange%3A(18%2C24)))),(or:(urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3Adegrees:List(urn%3Ali%3Adegree%3A2049))))))
```

As per ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-facet-urns
The Values for Age Range allowed are : urn:li:ageRange:(18,24) urn:li:ageRange:(25,34) urn:li:ageRange:(35,54) urn:li:ageRange:(55, 2147483647)

I am getting a 400 error

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request",
    "status": 400
}
```

Could you help me whether the encoding for date range in the query is correct or wrong?

Comment: Is there a response body in the 400 response? It might give you a hint as to what is failing validation.

Comment: {
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request",
    "status": 400
}

Comment: I tried plugging your query string into my test harness. I'm not able to get it to work either. One thing I did notice is that the facet for age ranges is plural, you have `urn%3Ali%3AadTargetingFacet%3AageRange`.  Another thing that I noticed is in the ad [budget call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ad-budget-pricing?tabs=http#encoded-sample-request), the parenthesis for ranges are URL encoded as well

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/ads/targeting-criteria-facet-urns#special-note) to, it states:
[image]

You're attempting to use age range in an exclude, and it can only be used in the include portion of targeting.